# Looking for a workaround for strtok

Tags: c, string, unix, char, strtok

I have to make a C shell interpreter that can handle multiple ' | ' operators. So if I write something like this: `cat test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` it works correctly. The problem comes when I try to use more complex functions, for example: `cat test.txt | awk '/" 404 / {print%7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head`. It breaks when 'awk' parameters are separated by strtok.

The code that works:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define ROW_SIZE 64
#define MIN 100000

void failed_allocation(){
    fprintf(stderr, "Faild to allocate memory.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char* read_line(){
    int buf_size = BUF_SIZE;
    int pos = 0;
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size);
    int c; // using int because EOF is -1

    if(buffer == NULL)
        failed_allocation();

    // read char by char
    while(TRUE){
        c = getchar();

        // look for EOF or end of line
        if(c == EOF || c == '\n'){
            buffer[pos] = '\0';
            return buffer;
        }
        else{
            buffer[pos] = c;
        }
        pos++;

        // if buffer max size is reached, then extend buffer
        if(pos >= buf_size){
            buf_size += BUF_SIZE;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, buf_size);
            if(buffer == NULL)
                failed_allocation();
        }
    }
}

char** split_to_lines(char* str, char* delim){
    int buf_size = ROW_SIZE;
    int pos = 0;
    char* buffer;
    char** buffer_list = malloc(buf_size * sizeof(char*));

    if(buffer_list == NULL)
        failed_allocation();

    // split into list
    buffer = strtok(str, delim);
    while(buffer != NULL){
        buffer_list[pos] = buffer;
        pos++;

        // if buffer max size is reached, then extend buffer
        if(pos >= buf_size){
            buf_size += ROW_SIZE;
            buffer_list = realloc(buffer_list, buf_size * sizeof(char*));
            if(buffer_list != NULL)
                failed_allocation();
        }

        buffer = strtok(NULL, delim); // continue reading str
    }
    buffer_list[pos] = NULL; // end list
    return buffer_list;
}

int start_proc(char** args){
    int fd[2];
    int prev_fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    int i;
    char** list = NULL;
    
    for(i = 0; args[i + 1] != NULL; ++i){
        if(pipe(fd) == -1){
            perror("Pipe error: ");
            return 1;
        }
        
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            perror("Fork error:");
            return 1;
        }
        else if(pid == 0){
            if(prev_fd != STDIN_FILENO){
                dup2(prev_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(prev_fd);
            }
            
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            
            list = split_to_lines(args[i], " \t\r\n");
            execvp(list[0], list);
            perror("Execvp error:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        close(prev_fd);
        close(fd[1]);
        prev_fd = fd[0];
        free(list);
    }
    
    if(prev_fd != STDIN_FILENO){
        dup2(prev_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(prev_fd);
    }
    
    list = split_to_lines(args[i], " \t\r\n");
    execvp(list[0], list);
    
    perror("Execvp error:");
}



int main(){
    int flag = TRUE;

    while(flag == TRUE){
        // input
        printf("\n> ");
        char* input = read_line();
        char** list = NULL;

        // exit condition
        if(strcmp(input, "exit") == 0)
            flag = FALSE;

        if(flag == TRUE){
            list = split_to_lines(input, "|");
            start_proc(list);
        }

        // free memory
        free(input);
        free(list);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried implementing my own way of separating strings, but in no vain as when trying to execute the code, it randomly creates empty space strings and then tries to execute them resulting in execvp errors.

This is the implementation that I tried:

```
int get_length(char* str){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}

int find_in_string(char* str, char look_for, int from){
    int length = get_length(str);
    if(from > length)
        return -1;
    
    for(int i = from; i < length; ++i){
        if(str[i] == look_for){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

char* substr(char* str, int begin, int end){
    int length = get_length(str);
    if(end > length || begin > length){
        fprintf(stderr, "Substr error: invalid interval values.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if(end < 0)
        end = length;
    else if(begin < 0)
        begin = 0;
    
    char* buffer = malloc((end - begin) * sizeof(char));
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = begin; i <= end; ++i){
        buffer[pos] = str[i];
        pos++;
    }
    buffer[pos] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

char** test_split_to_lines(char* str, char* delim){
    char* buffer;
    char** buffer_list = malloc(ROW_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
    int pos = 0;
    
    int cursor_pos = 0;
    int cursor_delim = 0;
    int length = get_length(str);
    
    loop:
    int delim_pos = MIN;
    for(int i = 0; delim[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        int temp = find_in_string(str, delim[i], cursor_delim);
        if((temp < delim_pos && temp > 0) || (temp < 0 && delim_pos == MIN) || (delim_pos < 0 && temp > -1))
            delim_pos = temp;
    }
    
    if(delim_pos == -1){
        buffer = substr(str, cursor_pos, -1);
        if(get_length(buffer) != 0){
            buffer_list[pos] = buffer;
            pos++;
        }
        buffer_list[pos] = NULL;
        return buffer_list;
    }
    
    int q_begin = find_in_string(str, 39, cursor_pos);
    int q_end = find_in_string(str, 39, q_begin + 1);
    
    if(delim_pos < q_begin || delim_pos > q_end){
        buffer = substr(str, cursor_pos, delim_pos - 1);
        buffer_list[pos] = buffer;
        pos++;
        
        cursor_pos = delim_pos + 1;
        cursor_delim = cursor_pos;
    }
    else{
        cursor_delim = q_end;
    }
    goto loop;
}
```

So, basically I need help writing a function, that correctly separates strings.

Comment: You could apply `strtok` again to the extracted `awk '/" 404 / {print%7}'`. But not until the first parse is complete, because `strtok` is not re-entrant: cannot be nested. Do the first parse with delimiter `"|"` and then continue processing every token afterwards, as a second stage.

Comment: The first parse that happens is in main and gives awk '/"404 / ... '. The problem is when its called again. It splits into a set of awk,  '/", 404, /, ...

Comment: Just use `"|\r\n"` delimitor for the first parse. Print each token to verify (at first). When you second-take each token, use appropriate filtering.

Comment: "I need help writing a function" is not a question we can answer for you.  However, the POSIX specs for the shell language actually contain [detailed specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) for how to parse shell commands.  Your particular case is probably simpler, but maybe that will give you some ideas.

Comment: You don't need to define TRUE and FALSE; just use the definitions from `stdbool.h`

Comment: This code smells like it's not guided by a textbook. What is `sizeof(char)`? I didn't know about `<stdbool.h>`, the potentially restrictive nature of `INT_MAX` when it comes to array sizes, or `size_t` until I started _reading manuals and textbooks_, either! Is there any reason why you're not modifying the string in place? It seems to me like dynamic allocation is complicating things for you. It's not an appropriate choice to duplicate storage when you're only going to forget about the original; just alter the original. Perhaps your book hasn't discussed _when (not) to use dynamic allocation_.

Comment: The standard idiom is `while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )`. It is standard because it genuinely helps avoid the infinite loops that you will undoubtedly encounter if you persist in using `while(TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split something to separate strings (it uses the original string, destroying it.) If `argv == NULL` it only count the number of strings

```
size_t splitstring(char **argv, size_t argvsize, char *str, const char *delim)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    if(str && *str)
    {
        if(argv)
        {
            memset(argv, 0, argvsize * sizeof(*argv));
            argv[pos] = str;
        }
        pos += 1;
        while(*str)
        {
            if(strchr(delim, *str))
            {
                *str++ = 0;
                if(argv)
                {
                    argv[pos] = str;
                    if(pos >= argvsize) break;
                }
                pos++;
            }
            else
            {
                str++;
            }
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I apologize in advance; this might not answer your question, but I wanted to demonstrate a novel technique. Instead of `strtok`, which has its problems, you can use `fmemopen` and `getdelim`, and use `open_memstream` to create an array to store the tokens that automatically grows big enough. The latter trick avoids error-prone calls to `realloc`. This also avoids having to write to the original string; although we don't declare it as `const`, it could be.

Note that trying to tokenize a string like this is only safe (whether you use this method or `strtok`) if you assume that '|' cannot occur as part of another multibyte character. I don't think ISO C guarantees this, but if the locale's encoding uses UTF-8, then you're safe.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    if(!setlocale(LC_ALL, "")) {
        fputs("Failed to enable default locale\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char command[] = "cat test.txt | awk '/\" 404 / {print%7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head";

    union {
        /* ISO C guarantees that the representations of char * and void * are
         * the same, so type-punning with a union is the same as doing a cast. */
        char *arrbytes;
        void *untyped;
    } outarray;
    size_t outarraybytecount;
    FILE *const outstream = open_memstream(&outarray.arrbytes, &outarraybytecount);
    if(!outstream) {
        perror("Failed to create memory stream");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *const readstream = fmemopen(command, sizeof(command) - 1, "r");
    if(!readstream) {
        perror("Failed to create memory stream");
        goto endoutstream;
    }

    do {

        char *tok = NULL;
        ssize_t k = getdelim(&tok, &(size_t){0}, '|', readstream);
        if(k == -1) {
            free(tok);
            if(ferror(readstream)) {
                perror("Failed to read from memory stream");
                goto endreadstream;
            }
        } else {
            if(tok[k-1] == '|') {
                /* You can leave the delimiter in if you want. */
                tok[k-1] = '\0';
            }
            /* This is a subtle trick: we're writing the contents of our pointer
             * variable to the stream. */
            if(!fwrite(&tok, sizeof(tok), 1, outstream)) {
                perror("Failed to write to memory stream");
                goto endreadstream;
            }
        }
    } while(!feof(readstream));

    /* Now we're done. */
    if(fclose(readstream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close memory stream");
        goto endoutstream;
    }
    if(fclose(outstream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close memory stream");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char **array = outarray.untyped;
    size_t arraylen = outarraybytecount/sizeof(*array);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < arraylen; i++) {
        puts(array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

endreadstream:
    if(fclose(readstream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close memory stream");
    }
endoutstream:
    if(fclose(outstream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close memory stream");
    } else {
        char **array = outarray.untyped;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < outarraybytecount/sizeof(char*); i++) {
            free(array[i]);
        }
        free(array);
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: _ISO C guarantees that the representations of `char *` and `void *` are the same_, but doesn't make such a portable guarantee about using conversions from `char *` to `char **` as you did in `char **array = (char**)outarray.untyped;` and then in those subsequent accesses. I don't think that parameter is intended to facilitate operation of a _2D array_, but instead to facilitate tracking of the file cursor (that is to say, only the first object pointed at is modified). Seems suspect to me...

Comment: @autistic I'll be glad to explain. `open_memstream` is specified to allocate memory for its output as if by `malloc`, so the memory is suitably aligned for accessing an object of type `char*`. And indeed, we are forming an array with elements of type `char *`, hence the double pointer. You've made me realize the casting is unnecessary converting from `void *`, so I've edited my answer.

Comment: I think there comes a point where these orthogonal tricks act as boilerplate to distract from the relevant content. The entire `union` can be eliminated if you use `(void *) outarray` rather than `outarray.untyped` (later on), for example, and half of the file handling and deallocation can be eliminated by operating on the string in-place (which would likely be beneficial to OP, since their user-provided content is likely already allocated somewhere)...